# Laravel Conditional Where clause not working

Tags: laravel

What I want is where user email equals email variable, then where status equals 1 or where the status is equals to 2. Either one should return result but for the given email

```
$existUser = DB::table('drivers')
    ->where('email', $email)
    ->where('status', '=', '1')
    ->orwhere('status', '=', '2')
    ->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$existUser = DB::table('drivers')
 ->where('email', $email)
        ->whereIn('status', [1, 2])
        ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    ->whereIn('status', [1, 2])
```

whereIn / whereNotIn / orWhereIn / orWhereNotIn

The whereIn method verifies that a given column's value is contained within the given array:

```
$users = Driver::where('email', $email)->whereIn('status', [1, 2])
    ->get();
```

Comment: sure, don't forget to make the answer is verified, thanks :)